# $.height returns 0 in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, colorbox

I am setting height of `td` as `auto` and wants to get `height` of that `td` to set to other `td` in `colorbox`. Here is my html

```
<tr>
    <td class="heading1" id="mhheading"><?php echo $this->translate("Medical History"); ?> </td>
    <td class="info1" style="height:auto;" id="mhinfo"><?php echo $this->patientDetail['medical_history'];?></td></tr>
```

I am getting height of `id="mhinfo"` and wants to set in `id="mhheading"`.

My jquery code is like here

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mhheading').css('height',$('#mhinfo').height());
    console.log($('#mhinfo').height());
});
```

I have seen in console it is returning `0`. I have used `window.load` and `document.load` but in all cases it is returning `0`.  Again I am using all this code in `colorbox`.

Comment: Is it visible when you are reading it?

Comment: yes visible. If I set height=34px; it return 34. but not return if set as auto

Comment: what does outerHeight() return?

Comment: @epascarello it returns 9 px. Altough the original height is very much than 9

Answer (score 0):

Dou you have table tags? I think you need to add table tag

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="heading1" id="mhheading"><?php echo $this->translate("Medical History"); ?> </td>
    <td class="info1" style="height:auto;" id="mhinfo"><?php echo $this->patientDetail['medical_history'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fTDTS/40/)